# what does line mean: var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB || {}; in js?

Tags: javascript

```
var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB || {};
```

I saw above code in one js file

Question:

what does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if DYN_WEB is not null it will take the value already set for DYN_WEB else assign an empty object to it.

Comment: This also applies for other values that evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

This is shorthand for

```
if ( ! DYN_WEB ) {
  DYN_WEB = {}
}
```

or

```
var DYN_WEB = DYN_WEB ? DYN_WEB : {}
```

Answer (score 0):

it means if the variable `DYN_WEB` has a value which is evaluated to binary true, then keep that value, otherewise assign `{}` to it. The latter will happen if the previous value of the variable is 'falsy' ie. one of the `false, null, undefined, NaN, 0, "", []` or `{}` and in case it's not defined.